# Is it more optimal on memory when you don't save off objects inside a loop and inline them?

Tags: java

Here is what am trying to figure out.

```
Case 1:
for(Foo foo : listOfFoos) {
  Bar bar = foo.getBar();
  if(bar == something) {
    //Do something else
    continue;
  }
}

Case 2:
for(Foo foo : listOfFoos) {
  if(foo.getBar() == something) {
    //Do something else
    continue;
  }
}
```

If this `list` consists of five million `Foo's`, would the second case be in anyway better than the first case in terms of speed or memory?

Comment: This does not matter at all, probably the byte code that the compiler produces for both is exactly the same.

Comment: Try it!! Build a random list, and time both. My bet is that no significant difference would be seen.

Comment: You could try setting a long with the current time when it starts and output the time it took when it finished and see which one is less or if they are the same.

Comment: do not worry about minor performance issues like this, unless your code is running on a potato. rather, choose the one that is more readable  to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Those two snippets are completely equivalent in terms of CPU and memory footprint.

The bytecode that `javac` emits is in fact slightly different. (An extra local variable and a pair of `astore`/`aload` is used in Case 1.) This is however still insignificant since the local variable *will* be inlined by the JVM/JIT.

Comment: How did you check the difference in the bytecodes? Is there a way you can compare .class files? Just curious.

Comment: There's a tool called `javap` that lives beside `javac`. Just do `javap -c YourClassWithoutExtension`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bar bar = foo.getBar();
```

This doesn't mean that it creates a copy of the `Bar` its just a pointer to the object returned by `getBar` method, which may or may not create additional memory. Hence the two Cases have same memory footprint.